# Where can I find a tycho pom first feature project to build a P2 repository?

Tags: pom.xml, tycho, p2

I want to generate a P2 repository from OSGI bundles that reside on maven central.
I have

1. defined a POM-first feature project using dependencies=consider
2. defined Maven dependencies with scope compile and type jar
3. defined a feature.xml with exact references to the bundle symbolic names and versions as declared in their manifest.mf

When I attempt to build the feature, I receive

```
No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.": ["Unable to satisfy dependency from org.codehaus.jackson.feature.group 1.9.1.qualifier to jackson-mapper-lgpl [1.9.12,1.9.13).", "Unable to satisfy dependency from org.codehaus.jackson.feature.group 1.9.1.qualifier to jackson-core-lgpl [1.9.12,1.9.13).", "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable."]
```

Where *org.codehaus.jackson.feature* is the feature I am building and *jackson-mapper-lgpl [1.9.12,1.9.13)* and *jackson-core-lgpl [1.9.12,1.9.13)* are the specifications of the OSGI bundles I am trying to include.

When I switch on debug mode, I see that the components are being found, which makes the behavior more odd:

```
[DEBUG] P2Resolver: artifact org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-lgpl:1.9.12 at location /home/jsuess/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-lgpl/1.9.12/jackson-core-lgpl-1.9.12.jar resolves installable unit jackson-core-lgpl/1.9.12
[DEBUG] P2resolver.addMavenArtifact org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-lgpl:jar:1.9.12:compile
[DEBUG] P2Resolver: artifact org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-lgpl:1.9.12 at location /home/jsuess/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-lgpl/1.9.12/jackson-mapper-lgpl-1.9.12.jar resolves installable unit jackson-mapper-lgpl/1.9.12
[DEBUG] Registered artifact repository org.eclipse.tycho.repository.registry.facade.RepositoryBlackboardKey(uri=file:/resolution-context-artifacts@/home/jsuess/workspace/org.codehaus.jackson/features/org.codehaus.jackson)
```

I believe taking bundles from maven and creating P2 must be a common use case, so I wonder if someone can point me to a working sample POM that I can use as a template.

Comment: When I switch on debug mode, I see that the components are being found, which makes the behavior more odd:

Comment: The missing bundle `jackson-mapper-core` is not in the `P2Resolver` debug output...

Comment: I have fixed that. Unfortunately it does not change the result. It now complains about both.
["Unable to satisfy dependency from org.codehaus.jackson.feature.group 1.9.1.qualifier to jackson-mapper-lgpl [1.9.12,1.9.13).", "Unable to satisfy dependency from org.codehaus.jackson.feature.group 1.9.1.qualifier to jackson-core-lgpl [1.9.12,1.9.13).", "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable."]

Comment: From the response I take it that this should work in principle?

Comment: I use the maven-dependency-plugin to download the bundles first. Then I use the Tycho extras [publish-features-and-bundles-mojo](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs-extras/tycho-p2-extras-plugin/publish-features-and-bundles-mojo.html) to create a p2 repository from the downloaded bundles.

Comment: Now this looks better and should work. Are you sure that you have put the configuration in the right places? Every module has a separate target platform, so the `P2Resolver` debug output may belong to a different module. You should be able to verify this by only building the feature alone.

Comment: Building the feature works without issue. The build of the repository fails. Both share the same target, as they inherit it from the super-POM.

Comment: Case closed. Typo in top-level declaration. Thanks for assistance. Will post the template here.

Comment: @oberlies do you want the template project to add to tycho? I am not sure where I could reasonably post it. If it is in tycho I can reference it and close this question.

Comment: I don't know what you mean exactly by "the template". But why don't you post whatever you needed to answer your question as an answer below. Stackoverflow encourages answering your own questions.

Comment: Was the typo "dependencies" instead of "pomDependencies"? I just spotted this mistake in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that every module in a Tycho build has a separate target platform.

So if you are using `pomDependencies=consider`, but you only configure this switch and/or the dependencies on an `eclipse-feature` module, the POM dependencies will only be in the target platform of the module. If you then try to package the feature into an `eclipse-repository`, the dependency resolution of that module will fail because of missing (transitive) dependencies of the feature.

In most cases, you don't need different target platforms per module, so in general you should put all [target platform configuration](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform) and POM dependencies into the parent POM.

---

If you have done this, but one of your modules still seems to have a different target platform, make sure that the parent POM reference of that module is correct - and that you don't reference an older version of your parent POM.